# clearTimeout is not working in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clear time using jquery clearTimeout() function when hover mouse on the div. But timer is not stopped. Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var timer= setTimeout(function()
    {display()},3000);

    $('.movieSlide').hover(function(){
       clearTimeout(timer) ;

    });
 });


function display(){
     var container=$('.movieSlide');
     var slideDiv=$('.movieSlide').find('.movieReview');

     slideDiv.css({"display":"none"});

     $(slideDiv[1]).css({"display":"block"});

     $(slideDiv[2]).css({"display":"block"});

     $(slideDiv[0]).appendTo(container);

     setTimeout(display,5000);

     }
```

I am not sure why it is not working and also no error in browser. thanks in advance.

Comment: You should fix your indentation.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling display again by using `setTimeOut` inside display scope (infinite loop) .On mouse hover you stop timer but another separate display already got fired. You can use `setInterval` instead .

Example https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/118/

Comment: Your answer is perfectly working for me. thanks a lot.